# Restrict Anonymous Users from accessing/viewing a Customized Form

Tags: 7, forms, users

I have created a form. The codes I used are below:

```
function myid_print_menu()
{
    $items = array(); 

    $items['user/%user/myid_print'] = array(
        'title' => 'Print an ID',
        'page callback' => 'myid_print_user_page',
        'page arguments' => array(1),    
        'access callback' => myid_print_user_access(),    
        'file' => 'myid_print.pages.inc',    
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'weight' => -10,
    ); 
    return $items;
}
```

The code of the function that allows accessing the form:

```
function myid_print_user_access()
{  
   if (user_access('perform_regular_task'))
   {
       return TRUE;
   }else{
       return FALSE;
   }

}
```

I was wondering that even if the user is not log-in the form can be access.

[image]

Looking at the module's permission:

[image]
[image]

I did not assign any permission for the `anonymous` user. Why it is so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The access callback element used in [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) takes a string has a value, you're supplying it the output of `myid_print_user_access()` which return a boolean. It should be:

```
'access callback' => 'myid_print_user_access',
```